# why $\{x\}\times Y\simeq Y$ and $X\times \{y\}\simeq X$?

Tags: general-topology, continuity

Fix $y\in Y$ and consider for every $x\in X$ the set, $$U_x=(\{x\}\times Y)\cup (X\times \{y\}).$$ Then every $U_x$ is connected for it is union of connected sets ($\{x\}\times Y\simeq Y$ and $X\times \{y\}\simeq X$) with non-empty intersection ($(\{x\}\times Y)\cap (X\times \{y\})=(x, y)$).

Now  My  QUESTION is that    why  $\{x\}\times Y\simeq Y$ and $X\times \{y\}\simeq X$?

My attempts  :  here  $\{x\} \neq  0$ ..as  $\{x\}\times Y\simeq \{x\}\times Y$

Im confused  ...

Pliz  help me

Comment: Claiming $U_x$ is connected is unwarrented.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The space $Y$ is homeomorphic to $\{x\}\times Y$ because there is the homeomorphism$$\begin{array}{ccc}Y&\longrightarrow&\{x\}\times Y\\y&\mapsto&(x,y).\end{array}$$It is a homeomorphism because it is continuous and its inverse, which is$$\begin{array}{ccc}\{x\}\times Y&\longrightarrow&Y\\(x,y)&\mapsto&y\end{array}$$is continuous too.

Comment: One should mention that it is bijective as well.

Comment: I did not mention that because it is implicit in my reference to the inverse.

Comment: Well, the existence of the inverse function implies only that the function is injective.

Comment: I think it's safe to say that if the inverse exists without any restriction to the values of the codomain, then it's a bijection. Also, the map referenced above is clearly a bijection.